# Symfony2 doctrine: How to select users that are not in groups with doctrine query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have symfony2 and fos user bundle installed and I'm trying to reproduce this MySql query in Symfony2 doctrine query builder.

This query should select users not belonging to listed groups.

```
SELECT *  FROM 
    fos_user_user 
left join 
    fos_user_user_group  on fos_user_user.id = fos_user_user_group.user_id   
    and fos_user_user_group.group_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
where 
    fos_user_user_group.user_id is null
```

Doctrine manual gives example that checks for user belonging to single group, but no reference when groupId **is array of several group ID's**. :groupId is not integer, doctrine gives an error.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM CmsUser u WHERE :groupId MEMBER OF u.groups');
$query->setParameter('groupId', $group);
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

Taken from [14. Doctrine Query Language](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Mysql scheme is default FOS User bundle. In simplified manner it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fos_user_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fos_user_group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `roles` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `deletedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fos_user_user_group` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `count` to the query, and add a `where count = 0` or `having count = 0` after that. This should return the users without a group.

Something like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id, COUNT(u.groups) as groupCount FROM CmsUser u WHERE groupCount = 0');
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? This is not aggregated query, so where count should be added?

Comment: How would you do that? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: What do you mean with example? The code sample is already there and is an extension of the one from the question.